# How to make the comments appear in the popup in Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**Update**

I have the popup working, but I'm having issues with the code. How can I display just the comments that are associated with a post in that popup? Please refer below for the code that I already have for the view.

I decided that using popups will be the easiest way to solve my current formatting issues. 
Basically, I have "comments" under each post. Instead of having them show below the post, I'd like to just have them come up in a popup when the link "X Comments" is clicked. The reason is that, I can't get the formatting correct when I try to have them appear underneath.

Here's the link I have for the # of comments in my view that will be clicked for the popup

```
<a href="#" id="comment_count"><%= micropost.comments.count.to_s %> Comment </a>
```

I'll implement the pluralizing of the text later.

This is the code for the comments associated with each post.

```
<div class ="ItemComments"><% if post.comments.exists? %>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>

   <%= image_tag("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=#{Digest::MD5::hexdigest(comment.user.email)}") %> <!-- Retrieves Gravatar -->

    <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>
            <span class="timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
    <span class="content2"><%= comment.comment_content %></span>
    <% end %></div>
```

The above view is rendered into _post.html.erb where it's shown

```
 <%= render 'shared/comment_form', post: post %>
```

How can I have the associated "comments" pop up when the link is clicked under each post?

Comment: usually it is done via jquery + some plugin/library like ligthbox/fancybox. did you try it?

Comment: I did. But I'm mostly concerned about the actual code. How can I make it display just the comments that are associated with a certain "post" when it's clicked? The code above works in my views\shared html.erb file but how can I make that work in a popup?

Comment: Updated original post with more info. I used facebox to get the popup working, but I'm having difficulties with the code to get only the comments associated to a post to display

Comment: How exactly does facebox hook into the dom? Or where/how do you configure the facebox popup? I guess you need something more specific in the surrounding div than the `class="ItemComments"`